# The app running on iOS 7.0 has iOS 6.0 interface

Tags: ios, ios7

I am running my app on iOS 7.0 and xcode 5 but the interface looks exactly like iOS 6.0, but the UIAlertView is iOS 7.0 like. I have configured the SDK to iOS 7.0 and the deployment target is  6.0. The app running fine in the simulator, looks exactly like iOS 7.0 flat. But why the app is still looks like 6.0 when the iphone is running iOS 7.0 system?

And why there are two selections with the same device name on top of the ios simulator selection panel? Are they the same?

I have successfully running my app on my iphone 5 device running ios 7.0 and it has ios 7.0 look and feel. But if I run it again, it goes back to ios 6.0 look. I changed nothing between. I really don't know what happened. It's frustrating.

Comment: Looks like the app was compiled for iOS 6. Check your deployment target settings.

Comment: my deployment target setting is iOS 6.0

Comment: You need to compile your app against iOS7 which you do by selecting the base SDK as iOS 7.0. If you have already done it, thats it then. It is doing what you are thinking it should/would.

Comment: I have selected the base sdk as ios 7.0.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out. Because I copied iOS 6.1 sdk to xCode 5, and when the iphone device is connected, xCode 5 shows the same device twice, one for iOS 6.1 and one for iOS 7.0, I must have selected the iOS6.1 as the running target, so I don't get the iOS 7.0 UI.

Comment: No, I already installed ios6 sdk on xcode5. I just pick wrong device to run. There are two devices have the same name, you just have to pick the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if only the device name was more relevant!, but is there a way to detect it at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

This is called compatibility mode,  because you are linking against the iOS6 your app will look and behave like if it is running under iOS6, if you want iOS7 look, you need to compile you application under xCode5 iOS7.

Consider to check these SO questions:

[When IOS 7 is launch will all application that is build for ios 6 look well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627599/when-ios-7-is-launch-will-all-application-that-is-build-for-ios-6-look-well)

[How to debug app in compatibility mode on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959986/how-to-debug-app-in-compatibility-mode-on-ios-7)

Comment: If I compile my app under iOS 7, will it still running under iOS 6? My deployment target is 6.0, and base sdk is ios 7.0. How can I have the iOS 7 look under iOS 7 and have ios 6 look under ios 6? What should be done?

Comment: you need to install iOS6 sdk on xCode5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882481/testing-ios-6-apps-on-device-running-ios7

Comment: I have installed ios6 sdk on xcode5. Because I can see it in the base sdk selections. any other solution?

Comment: Now you can compile your code on xCode 5 by choosing iOS 6 as a deployment target.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. choosing ios 6 as a deployment target.