# XCode 4.6.3 not detecting iphone device which has 7.0.2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

The OS version of my phone is `7.0.2 (11A501)`. I am using XCode `4.6.3`. The IDE Xcode is not detecting my iPhone. When i go to organizer it tells me the following

> The version of iOS on “Joe iPhone” is not supported by this
>   installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of
>   the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK;
>   which is available here.

However, i have read in various [forums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882481/testing-ios-6-apps-on-device-running-ios7) that if i download xCode 5 i will not be able to build for ios 5 or 6 applications. What should i do ? Help/

Answer (score 3):

It sometimes suffices to copy the device support files from a newer Xcode version to an older one. Try copying

Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.0 (11A465)

to your Xcode 4 installation, but name it "7.0.2 (11A501)"

Comment: I'm running Xcode 5 by the way, but I used this trick to be able to debug on my 7.0.2 device. Except I could symlink of course: `ln -s 7.0\ \(11A465\) 7.0.2\ \(11A501\)`

Comment: This trick works, however I didn't rename folder name to 7.0.2 (11A501). I'm using Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Indeed, no need to rename. Copying the correct device support folder from the Xcode 5 app package into my local Xcode 4 install did the trick. This solution works great if you can't install Xcode 5 because you are on < OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: Renaming depends on the version of the OS of the device you are debugging, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat trick to install the app on and iOS 7 device with Xcode 4.6

First download from the developer center Xcode 5 and install it manually in a separate folder in your Applications folder (I did add it in an Xcode foler, inside Applications).

So now you have both Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5 on your Mac.

Now, run your code on Xcode 5 and install it on your phone (press the debug button on your iOS device). Once this is done, you can quit Xcode 5, open Xcode 4.6 and it will be able to debug the app on your iOS7 device just fine!

Comment: But, do i have to still pay 18USD to purchase the OS X 10.8.5 ?

Comment: I didn't know that Xcode 5 requires 10.8 If it does, then I'm afraid you need to pay the $18

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to run iOS 6 apps easily from xCode 5 - no problem.
Updating xCode is only way to work with iOS 7 devices - you have no choice.

Comment: Well to download Xcode it requires  OS X 10.8.5 ? Do i have to pay for this ? I thought it was free ?

Comment: Upgrade to Lion is paid, but it's cheap

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Run your code in Xcode5 the again run in Xcode4.6 will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to update your xcode, or create an IPA and install it on your device with iOS 7.0.2 by iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, definitely you have to install XCode5. 
Initially you can build application only against IOS7, but you can manually add IOS6 SDK.

XCode SDK's are placed on this location:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

You can copy IOS6 SDK from this location of XCode4.6 and paste it into same location in XCode5.
This way you can choose will you build your application against IOS6 or IOS7.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in Xcode5 the again run in Xcode4.6 will solve problem.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to debug your Apps  in xcode with ios 7 then, Updating xCode  to version xcode 5  is only way to work with new ios (ios 7.0.2) and xcode  5 requirement is MAC os 10.8.4 , you have to update  your OS ,if you  right now using older version of operating system

Thanks